# Is Vite development server required for Laravel apps in production

Tags: laravel, windows, tailwind-css, vite, laravel-9

Im on a new `Laravel9`, `Vite3` and `TailwindCss3` project.

### The issue

Using `npm run build` isn't enough for deploying the app!

When I do not run Vite's development server I get the following error:

> Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/css/app.css.

But when I use `npm run dev` everything works fine!

---

### Reproducing

I used the following commands:

```bash
laravel new vite-test --git &&
cd .\vite-test\ &&
npm i &&
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer &&
npx tailwindcss init -p &&
php ./artisan serve
```

And edited the following files following the docs:

```html
<!-- resources\views\welcome.blade.php -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>

<body>
    <div class="h-screen w-screen bg-red-500"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
// tailwind.config.js

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

```css
/* resources\css\app.css */

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**Then:**

```
npm run build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the file separator used in `manifest.json` when Vite runs on Windows, and it is solved by upgrading Vite to [`^3.0.4`](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/commit/13e6450#diff-2cfbd4f4d8c32727cd8e1a561cffbde0b384a3ce0789340440e144f9d64c10f6).

After the upgrade:

```json
...
    "resources/css/app.css": {
        "file": "assets/app.7b7f948e.css",
        "src": "resources/css/app.css",
        "isEntry": true
    }
}
```

And before:

```json
...
    "resources/css\\app.css": {
        "file": "assets/app.7b7f948e.css",
        "src": "resources/css\\app.css"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There should be a file named 'hot' in the public folder of your Laravel project. Deleting that file will allow the resources to be loaded from the build folder generated by `npm run build` command.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I found no file with that name. on my project and on a fresh one

Comment: That file gets deleted automatically after stopping the dev server

Comment: This helped me - if the dev server gets killed or doesn't shut down cleanly, the `hot` file stays around.

Comment: it works. but, where is the documentation about that??

Answer (score 0):

Vite is a tool made to better your life while developing your project. This make use of hotswapping changes in your CSS files and blade files.

`npm run dev` compiles your assets with NODE_ENV=development set.

You don't need to run vite when publishing to your server

Comment: But have you tried to reproduce my example? I Followed the docs but when ever I browse the app without Vite's server running I get `Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/css/app.css.` **Error**.